# Can I make my Thread pool create its threads as foreground?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

By default the thread pool in .NET works with background threads.

I can't change it to run as foreground.

How do I change this to run as foreground threads?

Edit:

I need to use this because I'm changing my App due high volume processing (before it I was manually handling threads, which are Foreground ones by default), and I don't want to change my Application just to adapt it to a background threading scenario..

I'm wondering why Thread pool is not Foreground by default

Comment: You want them to be foreground to prevent your process from terminating?  You could keep a reference count as to how many active background threads you have an don't terminate your main (presumably foreground, UI) thread until the count reaches zero.

Comment: @jeffamaphone +1. Smells like "I do not know how to program that properly, so I take a hammer and somehow get it working, abusing everything I do not know".

Comment: Well, I don't want to assume too much, but I do prefer questions which include *why* you want to do something, as frequently there is a better way that comes from experience.

Comment: What do you mean by "due high volume processing".   If thread pool does not have the desired behavior then you should consider maybe it is not the right tool.

Comment: For the record, you *can* change the current ThreadPool thread to a foreground thread, but doing that is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Blam so you are saying I can't set it as Foreground, that's why you suggest I should choose another option?

Comment: Also a n00b here, but working with windows services the onstart function has to exit.  Couple this with launching processing with a timer, and you have a pretty good scenario where you don't want the onstop event's exit to destroy your process without time for cleanup.  Of course, you can create a separate forground thread to wait for the timer thread, but that's implementation -- the concept of foregrounding a worker pool thread seems valid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The notion of a "background thread" means *very* little in .NET.  The Thread.IsBackground property is just a simple flag that helps the CLR decide whether or not it should rudely abort the thread when the AppDomain gets unloaded or whether it should wait for the thread to exit voluntarily.

You can just change the property if you want a thread-pool thread to keep running at program exit.  This snippet shows how that's possible:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var sync = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Running");
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
            sync.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done, should exit now");
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        });
        sync.WaitOne();  // Ensures IsBackground is set
    }
}
```

Do keep your eyes on the ball here.  If this is important to you then there's a high likelihood you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** set thread pool threads as foreground.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Action(() => Worker()).BeginInvoke(null,null);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Main ends here");
    }

    static void Worker()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Worker started. Bg {0} Tp {1}.", 
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground, 
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Worker ends here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can, you will have to come up with a custom ThreadPool in order to do this.

> The threads in the managed thread pool are background threads. That is, their IsBackground properties are true. This means that a ThreadPool thread will not keep an application running after all foreground threads have exited.
>
> **When Not to Use Thread Pool Threads**
>
> There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and
>   manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:
>
> - You require a foreground thread.

[From this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
[And This One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0ka9477y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)